# DocumentDB tag created

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just created the [DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentdb) tag.  I failed to search adequately, and didn't notice that the [azure-documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-documentdb) already existed.

My tag has been edited off of all questions, so it points to nothing.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to correct this error and burninate this tag?

Comment: I think if it's not used on any questions, it will be automatically deleted by the system eventually. [Confirmed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71129/242495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

From the [burninate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info):

> Tags with no questions under them are automatically deleted by the
>   system within 24 hours and require no action on a moderator's part.

Standard burnination procedure (for fairly small-medium size tags) is for users with full edit privileges (2k+ rep) to go through all of the tagged questions, clean them up, and remove the tag if a consensus is reached ~1 week after the Meta posting.

When there are no tagged questions left, the tag will be deleted from the system within 24 hours and no one will be able to use that tag in their question without creating it again, which requires 1.5k rep.